# How to get multiple iFrame's on a loop

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I have my script which works fine for 1 to 3 web pages, however if I start putting anymore in I often get timeout errors. I'm wondering if there is a better way to write this code? Any ideas? Basically I have 6 iframes which I just want to loop around each one every 2 minutes or so. The data is refreshed once a day. Suggestions? It's a dashboard I've taken over from a colleague whose asked for help as he also experience problems.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Dashboard Example</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        body, html {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            overflow: hidden;
        }

        iframe {
            border: none;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            display: none;
        }

        iframe.active {
            display: block;
        }
    </style>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      var Dash = {
        nextIndex: 0,
        dashboards: [
          {url: "website here", time: 120, refresh: true},
          {url: "website here", time: 120, refresh: true}


        ],
        startup: function () {
          for (var index = 0; index < Dash.dashboards.length; index++) {

            Dash.loadFrame(index);
          }
          setTimeout(Dash.display, Dash.dashboards[0].time * 1000);
        },
        loadFrame: function (index) {
          var iframe =
            document.getElementById(index);
          iframe.src =
            Dash.dashboards[index].url;
        },
        display: function () {
          var dashboard = Dash.dashboards[Dash.nextIndex];

          Dash.hideFrame(Dash.nextIndex - 1);
          if
          (dashboard.refresh) {

            Dash.loadFrame(Dash.nextIndex);
          }

          Dash.showFrame(Dash.nextIndex);
          Dash.nextIndex = (Dash.nextIndex + 1) % Dash.dashboards.length;
          setTimeout(Dash.display, dashboard.time * 1000);
        },
        hideFrame: function (index) {
          if (index < 0) {

            index = Dash.dashboards.length - 1;
          }

          $('#' + index).css({
            opacity: 1.0, visibility:
              "visible"
          }).animate({opacity: 0.0}, 2000);

          setTimeout(function () {
            true;
          }, 2000);

          document.getElementById(index).removeAttribute('class');
        },
        showFrame: function (index) {

          $('#' + index).css({opacity: 0.0, visibility: "visible"}).animate({
            opacity:
              1.0
          }, 200);

          document.getElementById(index).setAttribute('class', 'active');
        }
      };

      function fetchPage(url) {
        $.ajax({
          type: "GET",
          url: url,
          error: function (request, status) {
            alert('Error fetching ' + url);
          },
          success: function (data) {
            parse_hadoop_active_nodes(data.responseText);
          }
        });
      }

      function parse(data) {
        alert($(data).find("#nodes").text());
      }

      window.onload = Dash.startup;
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<iframe id="0" class="active"></iframe>
<iframe id="1"></iframe>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use one IFrame and change the src url of the IFrame instead of creating one IFrame per page you want to display, so instead of showing and hidding IFrames you change the src url.

If loading time is long or its important the dashboards be preloaded, you can use 2 iframes.

For looping you might want to look into using [requestAnimationFrame](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame)